# Is there difference which number in SIM1?

Tags: sim, blu-win-hd

I have BLU WIN HD LTE with dual sim.

Should I place my primary number as SIM1 or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier for you to remember it putting your primary SIM in slot 1 but it does not have any consequences functionality-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference. Only the first SIM slot supports LTE.

EDIT:
I was using this device as SS device. When I used my SIM in first slot I had LTE and when using in second slot it was 3G only. I remember that I've checked max speed in setting and it was LTE for first and 3G for second slot. There are maybe different versions for Europe/North America/ Asia. P.S. This Indian website also states that second slot is 3G only: [gadgets.ndtv.com/blu-win-hd-lte-2858](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/blu-win-hd-lte-2858)

Comment: Are you sure this is the case? From reading a few reviews, I got the impression that both SIM slots support 4G LTE, but only one can be assigned to handle the data connection (whereas calls and text messages can go through either SIM).

Comment: I have had this device for a short period of time, and 4G worked only in first SIM slot :/ My unit was maybe faulty, I don't know.
P.S. I'm from Europe

Comment: Did you look for the setting to switch mobile data over to the other SIM? Or are you saying the other SIM only worked at up to 3G speeds? Did you check SIM settings? Did the other SIM have a 4G plan and a good enough signal?

Comment: I was using it as SS device. When I used my SIM in first slot I had LTE and when using in second slot it was 3G only. I remember that I've checked max speed in setting and it was LTE for first and 3G for second slot.
There are maybe different versions for Europe/North America/ Asia. 

P.S. This Indian website also states that second slot is 3G only: http://gadgets.ndtv.com/blu-win-hd-lte-2858

Comment: Why not edit your answer to include links to those references?

Comment: Probably you're right, but I'd like to get confirmation.